# Android 6.0 : java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host. Working fine in Android 7.0

Tags: java, android

There is issue of java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "URL": No address associated with hostname

Here is what I tried.

- Turn on/off Wifi
- Test in Mobile Network
- Check in Postman
- Runtime permission integrated
- INTERNET permission is also there.

Above solutions is working fine in Android 4.4.4, 6.0, and also 7.0.

But this is not working only on 6.0.

Comment: are you sure that the problem is not device-specific? have you tried multiple 6.0 devices?

Comment: Unable to resolve host "URL": did you literally use a hostname "URL"?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yes I tested In 3 6.0 Devices. There is same problem in all 3 6.0 devices.

Comment: @Henry. No, I use my  API URL insted of "URL".

Answer (score 1):

After several attemps I found unreadable characters when setting the URL at my code. Opening the source file with VIM, I found:
http://this.is.an.ip**<200b>**/

Where ***<200b>*** is an unreadable character at my IDE (Android studio).

After the deletion of **<200b>** my app started running ok at Android 5/6.

Good luck!